# Comparing the complexity of $n!$ and $4^n$

Tags: computational-complexity

$1 < \log ⁡n < n < n\log ⁡n < n^2 < n^3< \ldots < 2^n < 3^n < 4^n < \ldots < n! < n^n$

I am trying to find out if $n!$ is greater than $4^{n}$. One way to attempt to solve this is to compare $n!$ with $4^{n}$ by taking a limit as $n$ approaches infinity, and for that, I would use the limit:

$$
\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{n!}{4^{n}}
$$

But to solve this limit, I needed to use L'Hôpital's Rule, by taking the derivative of both the numerator and the denominator.

However, I cannot directly differentiate $n!$ since it is a discrete function. To handle this, I used the `Gamma function`, which is a continuous function such that $\Gamma(n-1) = n!$

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty }t^{n-1}\cdot e^{-t}dt}{4^{n}}
$$

However, I am having trouble finding an answer that indicates whether $n!$ grows faster than $4^{n}$ or not.

Could you help me? I'm not sure what strategy to use

Comment: Just note that $n$ is larger than 5 for all $n>5$. =) or use a ratio test. Using the gamma function is overkill.

Comment: Another method for finding limits involving factorials like this is using Sterling's approximation. This may work nicely if the function in denominator is harder to bound.

Comment: This problem doesn't need any calculus: it is easy to prove by induction (after a little calculation to find a base case). See the answer given by Darth Geek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use induction on $n$. Prove the fact for some $n > 4$. Then
$$4^{n+1} = 4\cdot 4^n < 4n! < (n+1)n! = (n+1)!$$

Comment: Indeed! It's obviously true by induction if it's ever true. You wrote up your answer while I was making sure that where was an $n$ for which it is true $\ddot{\smile}$. Is there a slicker way than brute force to see why there must be such an $n$?

Comment: Is the following way of reasoning correct for $4\cdot4^{n} < 4n!$ ? To
$n > 4$, so the first digit of n is 5. So
$4\cdot4^{5} = 4096$ and
$4n! = (4\cdot5) \cdot (4\cdot4) \cdot (4\cdot3) \cdot (4\cdot2) \cdot (4\cdot1)$ or $4\cdot(5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1)$

Comment: Stirling's approximation tells you that $n! \sim (\frac ne)^n$, so I would look around $4e \approx 10$.  In fact $9$ is [enough](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table+n%21-4%5En+for+n+from+6+to+14)

Comment: @rafaelcb21 You have to prove it for some $n > 4$ but it might not be true for all $n > 4$. As Ross Millikan pointed out, you have to go as far as $n = 9$ to prove it.